# subtraction operation with 2 random numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple math game for my son. I have the addition operation working perfect.  My problem is with subtraction.  I am using the same code as my addition operation, problem is sometimes the 2nd number is larger than the 1st number resulting in a negative number.  I need help correcting the order of the random numbers so the 1st number is greater than or equal to the 2nd number.  Please help.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int answer;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int SIDES = 6;
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
    int b = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
    System.out.println("What is " + a + " - " + b + " = ");
    int difference = a - b;
    Scanner one = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the answer?");
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(one.next());
    //int answer = one.next();
    System.out.println("your answer is " + answer);
    if (answer==difference) {
       System.out.println("You are correct!");
       System.out.println("You gain 5 points");
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("You are wrong.");
       System.out.println("The correct answer is " + difference);
       System.out.println("You lose 5 points");
   }
```

Comment: [`Math.min(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-), [`Math.max(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-)? As an aside: you can remove the unused attributes `input` and `answer`. And please fix your indentation.

Comment: Is that just using `Math.abs()` on the result acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, but in order not to mess up your code, an easy fix would be checking the 2 generated random numbers before assigning them to `a` and `b`:

```
int r1 = (int) Math.random()*SIDES;
int r2 = (int) Math.random()*SIDES;

int a = Math.max(r1, r2);
int b = Math.min(r1, r2);
```

This way, `a` will always be greater or equals to `b`.

Comment: I used this suggestion and it worked flawlessly.  Thank you.

Comment: Downvoter, care to drop a reason for this down vote?

Comment: Would have been inadvertent.  I am will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an inequality operator to compare their values, than subtract from the larger one:

```
int difference = a > b ? a - b : b - a;
//                 ^ Inequality operator
```

If the `?` operator is confusing you, you can alternatively write it like this:

```
int difference;
if(a > b) difference = a - b;
else difference = b - a;
```

You can read more about operators such as `?`, `>`, `&&`, `||`, etc. on the [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) page.

Comment: Simpler, you can use `int difference = Math.abs(a - b)` to get the same results.

Comment: @Alex I considered that, but did not want to invoke other classes. :P

Comment: That doesn't change the question posed to the son. The question will still be  "What is 2 - 6" but now the expected answer is 4 rather than -4. That seems confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that your `b` never becomes bigger than `a` by adjusting your random number generation logic:

```
int b = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * a);
```

That's probably better than swapping the numbers, because swapping will skew `a` to the high end (close to `SIDES`) which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only subtracting two numbers you can simply use if(a >= b) then a - b else b - a to control the order.

If there are more numbers in the question you can always put all the random numbers into an array and sort them before generating the question.